# UIViewController landscape mode buttons not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to get an app working in landscape mode which I've very nearly done, but for some reason the buttons on my view aren't working (ie. they don't press).  I'm using a root view controller which loads the initial view controller as follows :

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad 
{

        [super viewDidLoad];

        StartViewController *viewController = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartView" bundle:nil];
        self.startViewController = viewController;
        startViewController.delegate = self;
        [viewController release];

        [self.view addSubview:startViewController.view];
    }
```

I've also set the Initial Interface Orientation value in my Info.plist file and overridden the following in my root view controller :

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) ||
           (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

The view loads fine and fills the screen in landscape mode as it should, but for some reason I just can't press any of the buttons on the view.

I'm sure it's something simple related to me using a root view controller because I've managed to get this to work fine before with an app with just a single view controller.

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: have you defined a method for a button click?

Comment: just wondering: any reason you're not managing a stack of view controllers with a uinavigationviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes, I've defined and linked the button click to a method.  The problem is that I can't actually press the button - it's there, I can see it, but it won't press.  It works fine in portrait mode.

Comment: The reason I haven't used a UINavigationViewController is because I'm going through a series of UIViewControllers in a semi-random way and the first example I saw of how to do this used a root view controller which seems to be a fairly common method.  The thing is, it works fine in portrait mode, so I can't see any reason I shouldn't be able to transfer it to landscape.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is somewhere in xib.
E.g. the button is placed on `UIView` with incorrect resize masks. So that in landscape mode the button appears outside the view, and touches can't reach the button. You can check it setting `clipSubviews` in all the parent view -- if I'm right, you will not see the button any more.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simular problem.  In my case I was subclassing a UITableViewCell and I has overwritten the layoutSubviews method. In there I was doing translations. But I forgot to put the [super layoutSubviews]; before my implementation. After I put it htere, the button were working again in landscape mode. It was strange that in portrait it worked and in landscape not.